# Wordpress site not redirecting to dashboard after login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I am trying to login on my wp site, when I am given correct admin details the landing page coming up and there are no admin dashboard showing, I tried many more plugin disabled option but the problem not solved, even I tried to reset password for admin access after changed it the same result appeared like no dashboard section rather than frontend. Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some others developed the site. If you are coder/programmer try the below

1. Login to hosting
2. Open PHP My Admin or any mysql UI tool
3. Open Prefix_users, usually this will be wp_users
4. see list of users and check if you have admin permissions. Sample below
   user_id - specific user id
   meta_key - wp_capabilities
   meta_value - a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

then save the DB record. Else get programmer support